# Cannot validate JWT with no kid in its header golang

Tags: go, jwt, token

I am trying to verify JWT token provided by a thiredpary, but the token doesn't having the `kid` in its header. while parsing it showing error message as below

```
  `Error: the JWT has an invalid kid: could not find kid in JWT header`
```

I am using `github.com/golang-jwt/jwt/v4` package to parse

JWT Header contain below values only

```
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

related code part given below

```
    // Parse the JWT.
    tokenParsed, err := jwt.Parse(token, jwks.Keyfunc)
    if err != nil {
        ch.Log(alog.FATAL, "Failed to parse the JWT.\nError: %s", err.Error())
    }
```

How can I verify the JWT Token  with no `kid` in its header

Comment: The error doesn't come from the `jwt` library. It comes from the `jwks` package, which is `github.com/MicahParks/keyfunc`. The field `kid` is required for jwks keys. Perhaps you want to use a different keyFunc here.

Comment: can you suggenst any alternative keyFunc to use here

Comment: where does the key come from? `jwks` is a variable that you declared earlier - and holds that data of a JSON Web Key Set. It needs a kid to find out which key to use. If there is no kid - how do *you* now which key should be used? Once you know that, you can implement your keyfunc based on the answer.